# Can I sue a Canadian company in the USA?

Tags: intellectual-property, litigation, collections

I had a consulting company (IT services) in Canada and my major client (also a Canadian corp) did not pay for large amount of software engineering services that I've done for them. They are actively selling their products to major European and US corporations (like Verizon, AT&T, Microsoft) and all these products are heavily based on and incorporate works done by me that they didn't pay for.

This my client Canadian corp most likely has US presence and I'm currently tax resident in the US. Can I sue this Canadian corp in the US (or their US subsidiary if it exists)? Can I sue their clients for using my works (or notify them to stop using them), what are possible consequences? Any pointers where I can get legal consultation in the San Francisco bay area regarding this matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try, however, a US court when considering if it has jurisdiction will doubtless ask you to explain why a Canadian business wants to sue a Canadian company for an unpaid debt in Canadian dollars for services provided in Canada in a US court.

If you can satisfy them that a US court is the appropriate venue (which I doubt) they will hear the case.